# boto CloudFormation BadRequest (400), Exception: None

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, aws-cloudformation

I'm implementing CloudFormation in boto and ran into a weird exception.

```
[sebastian ~/test_project (develop)]$ ./manage.py --template cf-templates/test_project.json --stack labs --validate
Validating template cf-templates/test_project.json..
Template cf-templates/test_project.json is valid!
[sebastian ~/test_project (develop)]$ ./manage.py --template cf-templates/test_project.json --stack labs --start
Creating stack labs with template cf-templates/test_project.json..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 311, in <module>
    main()
  File "./manage.py", line 113, in main
    start_stack(cf_con, parser, args, config)
  File "./manage.py", line 261, in start_stack
    template_body=get_json_from_template(args.template))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/cloudformation/connection.py", line 208, in create_stack
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
None
```

As you can see I am executing two commands. The first one calls `validate_template` and it is OK. The second one calls `start_stack` like this:

```
cf_con = cloudformation.connect_to_region(
    args.region,
    aws_access_key_id=config.get(
        args.config_section, 'aws_access_key_id'),
    aws_secret_access_key=config.get(
        args.config_section, 'aws_secret_access_key'))

cf_con.create_stack(
    args.stack,
    template_body=get_json_from_template(args.template))
```

I don't really know what the problem might be as all I get back from boto is `None` in the error message. But maybe that is an indication of something?

Any pointers in the right direction is highly appreciated!

PS. It works fine to start the stack from AWS Console with the same template. DS.

Comment: Could you try running this with debug logging enabled?  It would be useful to see the actual request/response.  See https://gist.github.com/1539859 for info about setting up debug logging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for the help garnaat, when debugging I saw the following:

```
2012-10-14 19:18:58,377 foo [ERROR]:400 Bad Request
2012-10-14 19:18:58,377 foo [ERROR]:{"Error":{"Code":"InsufficientCapabilitiesException","Message":"Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]","Type":"Sender"},"RequestId":"389d102d-1623-11e2-b536-cb51e58a0a52"}
```

So I have added the capability to the code:

```
cf_con.create_stack(
    args.stack,
    template_body=get_json_from_template(args.template),
    capabilities=['CAPABILITY_IAM'])
```

Comment: Vaguely related the same is true if you are using python AWS cli. You have to append  --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM to the command line.